# Woocommerce Shop custom page

Tags: woocommerce

I all,
I need to create a custom shop page using wordpress. I have two main categories. Food and Drinks and I would like to have the same woocommerce products grid style, but divided in two. One for Food and One for Drinks.

I am using page-shop.php template on my theme, and this page simply loops posts.

How can I accomplish this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by using the default woocommerce product category page such as https://yoursite.com/product-category/drink - assuming you have added drink as a product category.

Comment: I have 2 main categories. Category Food and Category Drinks. So I would like to have 2 dedicated blocks on my shop page. 1 with 10 products for Food and 1 for 10 products for drinks. Kind of like the best sold products boxes.